# Lookup or find with multiple values and multiple return values

Tags: excel, vba

vba beginner here.

I have 2 worksheets, in worksheet 1 (sht1), I have 2 columns of index numbers (Column A & column U)
What I am required to do is to compare the list of index numbers in sht1 column U against Column B in worksheet 2 (sht2) and from there, retrieve the corresponding data in the same row of sht2 columns I & M and concatenate the 2 values together to input into sht1 Column V

However, if the value in sht1.column U cannot be found, I want to do a similar search using the index number from sht1.Column A from the same row.

I am pretty much stumped as to how I can go about it.  Again, I’m trying to do the above without applying `activecell` and `.select` but am stuck as the number of rows in worksheet 1 and worksheet 2 are different and as such, I can't use `for...next`.

Comment: Any chance of screenshots? A picture paints a thousand words!

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? This could be done in a formula in the cell...  Lookups are good in worksheet functions... If it has to be VBA, you can make use of the worksheet functions (e.g. `MATCH`) inside your VBA (e.g. `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`) - faster than trying to write your own lookups...

Answer (score 0):

As a formula:

```
=INDEX('Sht2'!I:I,IFERROR(MATCH(U2,'Sht2'!B:B,0),MATCH(A2,'Sht2'!B:B,0))) & INDEX('Sht2'!M:M,IFERROR(MATCH(U2,'Sht2'!B:B,0),MATCH(A2,'Sht2'!B:B,0)))
```

As a function,

- loop over your rows in sht1
- call `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` in place of `MATCH` with your `U` index value
- if it is an error, repeat with `A` index value

  - To catch an check for the error, use something like:
    `foundRowNum=0`
    `On Error Resume Next`
    `foundRowNum=Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("lookdccfup",ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sht2").Range("B:B"),0)`
    `On Error Goto 0`
    `If foundRowNum = 0 Then ...`
- use the resulting row index to reference `sht2.Cells(xxx,9) & sht2.Cells(xxx,11)`